# How to get indexes of elements in a table using python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I think the question is pretty straightforward and needs no further explanation. Basically, if I have a table, how can I get the row and column number based on the element. For example:

```
0 | 1 | 2
-----------
1 | a | b
-----------
2 | c | d
```

How could I input b and get 1, 2?

Comment: as table is not a built-in data structure you should show your current code so we can help you

Comment: sorry to say but no, the question is not straightforward. What kind of table is this? is it a text file with that as your text? is it a list of list? is it a 2-d array?

Comment: What should the result be like if there are duplicate entries?

Comment: Sorry, I hope I have explained it better now. @albert I assume there are no duplicate entries.

Comment: What is the size of the table? Iterating through a rather big table could be really slow.

Comment: @albert it is set by the user and not limited

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply iterate through your data until you find the element you want:

```
def find_index(T,x):
    for i in range(len(T)):
        for j in range(len(T[i]):
            if T[i][j] == x:
                return i,j
```

Answer (score 1):

This will return a list of tuples, each tuple containing an x and y coordinate. It operates on a list of lists, so basically a 2-dimensional list. I believe this is what you want.

```
def find_all(list_2d, value):
    for row_index, row in enumerate(list_2d):
        for col_index, val in enumerate(row):
            if val == value:
                yield col_index, row_index
```

This just iterates over the whole "table" and yields the coordinates each times it matches.

If you do not care about duplicates and just want to get the first coordinates, something like this will work

```
def find_first(list_2d, value):
    for row_index, row in enumerate(list_2d):
        try:
            return row.index(value), row_index
        except:
            pass
```